# How to make Lubuntu login automatically?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, lightdm, auto-login

I want to know how to make Lubuntu 14.04 restart every two hours, login, and open a program. I am currently stuck on the first part which is to make it login automatically. I have tried changing lightdm.conf and lightdm.conf.d folder, and default.conf to no avail. What should I do?

Comment: Try this advice for autologin: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1472113

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Lubuntu documentation,  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Boot_Install_Login#For_release_12.04_and_on_.28LightDM.29,
You will need to create an /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf with these contents: (do this as root)

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=<YOUR USER>
autologin-user-timeout=0
# Check https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/854261 before setting a timeout
user-session=Lubuntu
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Comment: This file doesn't exist, and when I created this and added this information in, it didn't work.

Comment: nvm, I found the problem. Your anwser did help though, thanks!

Comment: @Byte11 could you please post the answer then?

Comment: @DavidCabrera I really can't remember since it was so long ago. I remember doing some modification on a file in nano that had something to do with how the su, sudo, or restart command worked. That's all I can vaguely remember, sorry. I do know that it is in fact possible in Lubuntu 14.04 without installing outside software.

Comment: found a solution... posted it as answer

Answer (score 7):

This solution worked for me. The link (at the bottom) is dead but I got a cached version.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Add the following lines replacing myusername with your user:

```
[Seat:*]
pam-service=lightdm
pam-autologin-service=lightdm-autologin
autologin-user=myusername
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

To check use:

```
$ /usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config
```

Source: http://www.neatlittleinsights.com/htdocs/lubuntu_16.04_autologin.html

Answer (score 7):

Lubuntu uses LightDM for login, You need to modify the config file. You need to check, where are they:

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config
```

You will see the proper config files under the "**Sources**" paragraph.

Then you can edit the first one with root privileges (eg. for Ubuntu 17 this is):

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf
```

Add your username to the autologin-user line (or add the line if it is not defined). It will look like:

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=lubuntu
autologin-user=myusername
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Save and check again with

```
/usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an arbitrarily named file in `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` e.g. `10-autologin.conf`.

with the content

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest = false
autologin-user = USERNAME
autologin-user-timeout = 0

[SeatDefaults]
allow-guest = false
```

Check with `sudo /usr/sbin/lightdm --show-config` which will show different settings with a capital letter indicating from with file they come from. In my case, the relevant letter is `I`:

```
   [Seat:*]
E  user-session=ubuntu
C  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
D  guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
H  greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
G  xserver-command=X -core
I  autologin-guest=false
I  autologin-user=ben
I  autologin-user-timeout=0
I  allow-guest=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Lubuntu 20.04 -
based on

- https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.1/3.1.9/sddm_configuration.html
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1130768/207905

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sddm.conf
[Autologin]
User=myusername
Session=Lubuntu
```