# Ubuntu 16.04 - Auto-login with lightdm

Tags: login, lightdm

I installed a minimal ISO of Ubuntu 16.04 (54 MB) on my virtual machine. After done installing the OS, I installed these programs:

- open-box
- lightdm
- Qt
- dokey

and some related libraries like "libgl1"

Everything works fine but when I did try to do the auto-login, I got stuck.

I have read many forums and watched a lot of videos, consequently found ways but none of them seems to work for me. The one which I'm eager to work with is `lightdm.conf` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

In the file, first thing I did was to delete the guess and it worked fine but the rest of the code dose not work at all. I double checked my username using `whoami`:

```
[SeatDefaults] 
allow-guest=false
autologin-user=saeed
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
```

Since I am not using Unity, I did not write (but I did try the code before) this code:

```
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

`saeed` is my only user now. However, I did try making another and do the auto-login with it, but the result was unsatisfying.

It's been around 12 hours of searching and trying. It seems that everybody is getting the result by above method, but I keep getting the login screen, I am afraid I might be short on some lib or something.

Since I am working on an embedded device (Intel based CPU, not ARM) it is crucial to get rid of the login in the main device (server) for the user behind LCD, nevertheless I do need the password for SSH connections security.

What can I do?

Comment: I've seen similar questions before which really haven't gotten a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lubuntu 16.10: How to make login through greeter without typing password work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892642/lubuntu-16-10-how-to-make-login-through-greeter-without-typing-password-work)

Comment: I'd make sure the `user-session` is really ubuntu. Check  the output of `env | grep DESKTOP_SESSION`.

Comment: i did search for my desktops . it didnt work , i even tested on a fully Ubuntu . there is a post in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2372864&p=13691965#post13691965 i did include pictures and more details

Comment: ok i didi change SeatDefault to [Seaat:*] and give delay 1 and delete the user session 
now the login screen is ***** . every second it crashes and resets a gain . so i can not even open the terminal using alt+ctrl+f1 . i think i have to start all over again . i wish i did get some backup . this is really annoying

Comment: ok i did replace lightdm with slim
the problem now is that in login screen slim can't recognize openbox 
i have to push F1 once so that "session : openbox" text appear on the screen otherwise i get fail and slim will reset no matter how many times i try, base on what i said the auto-login will fail , how can i make the openbox my default session for slim ? i have seen some videos in youtube , it seems that slim can recognize openbox in full version ubuntu