# How to enable autologin on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS (LightDM)

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, lightdm, auto-login

There are many instructions on how to enable autologin on various Ubuntu-based distros. However, I couldn't find a solution explicitly for Lubuntu 16.04 LTS with LightDM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution in this thread about Lubuntu 16.10: [Lubuntu 16.10: How to make login through greeter without typing password work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/892642/lubuntu-16-10-how-to-make-login-through-greeter-without-typing-password-work)

1. Open new configuration file with Leafpad (or your preferred editor)

   ```
   sudo leafpad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-autologin.conf
   ```
2. Paste the following lines

   ```
   [Seat:*]
   autologin-guest = false
   autologin-user = yourusername
   autologin-user-timeout = 0

   [SeatDefaults]
   allow-guest = false
   ```
3. Replace `yourusername` with the name of the user you want to have logged in automatically

Comment: So why are you creating this question / answer ? It is a duplicate of both question and answer ??? Also, if all else fails, `sudo nano ....` also works.

Comment: We do not write an answer for each release unless there is something specific to that release. So if the answer works for 16.04 and 16.10 , as it seems in your case, we would not write an answer for each release. Hope that is clear, but, you can always ask on meta also.

Comment: It is helpful information to know what release someone is using "just in in case". I highly suggest you ask for guidance on meta to get community input rather then in comments here. https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions

Comment: It works for 18.04 too.  I would have said, if all else fails, use vi ...  You may not always get leafpad or nano or any other editor that is the flavour of the month or the flavour of the distribution, but you will almost always get vi.