# How Do you Autologin in Lubuntu 18.10?

Tags: lubuntu

I'm not sure, but lightDM doesn't seem to work

Comment: `lightdm` should work (it does on my 18.10 box);  I'm unsure how to set autologin using it though (I've never tried).

Comment: And please read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1112349/how-to-enable-guest-sessions-on-ubuntu-18-04-or-later/1112356#1112356

Comment: I see the page, but I want something to work without installing something else, otherwise I would have installed slim.  In 18.10 there is no configuration file for lightdm
and I looked in /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to Preferences -> KDE.System.Settings (in the menu)

In the *Login Screen (SSDM)* setting there is a checkbox for *Auto Login*.  Ensure the check-box is clicked and your username should become easily readable.

[image: Lubuntu 18.10 KDE Settings - SDDM]

Answer (score 2):

**USE SDDM which comes standard in lubuntu 18.10**

Had to edit `/etc/sddm.conf`

Here is an example sddm.conf:

```
[Autologin]
Relogin=false
User=christian
Session=Lubuntu
```

Comment: I'm not sure that "SDDM … comes with lubuntu 18.04". It is the default in Lubuntu 18.10.

Comment: The Question is specifically for 18.10.

--nvm I see what you mean. 
Fixed!